# Getting th element in table of specific index in protractor

Tags: html-table, protractor

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>place</th>
        <th>area</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>jjhds</td><td>dfdsf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>jjhds</td><td>dfdsf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>jjhds</td><td>dfdsf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>jjhds</td><td>dfdsf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>jjhds</td><td>dfdsf</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have above table. I need to navigate from **td** in **tbody** and get its heading in **thead****th** through protractor. Please can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? may be put some logic you have tried already. That way it's easier to help you out with selectors or understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to get the desired header by an index of a column in a row, sample:

```
var table = $('table');  // TODO: too general of a locator, improve
var headers = table.$$('th');
table.$$('tr').each(function (row) {
    row.$$('td').each(function (cell, index) {
        cell.getText().then(function (cellText) {
            headers.get(index).getText().then(function (headerText) {
                console.log("Header: " + headerText + ", Cell Value: " + cellText);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Using [`.each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) here just for demonstration purposes.